# Oscillator starts precisely on edge, i.e. synchronous

Tags: oscillator, synchronous

I want to build a circuit that oscilates synchronous to a real-time capable Raspberry Pi.

From the outside, an edge will be sent to both devices. That time is the zero point. All output oscilator edges have to come at a 50 Hz frequency as accurately as possible to the zero point. The edge height has to be 5 V.

I want to send ultrasonic signals from the device that has the oscilator in it, and catch them with the Raspberry Pi. After the zero point is set on both devices they will have no physical connection to each other.

Where do I begin?

I assume that an NE555 is not precise enough.

Comment: This will be difficult if you only have one "zero point" edge.  If your edge occurs on a regular frequency then you may be able to use a Phase Locked Loop (PLL) to discipline your output edges.  If you do only have a single zero point edge then your output edges will be subject to drift unless disciplined by another periodic edge source.  What oscillators / clock discipline sources are available to you?

Comment: "After the zero point is set to both devices they will have no physical connection to each other." it sounds like what you really want are two very accurate clocks that will stay close after being synchronized.  The longer you want them to stay close enough, the more expensive this will be.  2.4 GHz Radio modules that could be used instead to share synchronization on an ongoing basis cost as little as a dollar for each end, if you already have a processor with an SPI interface.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding the 50Hz has nothing to do with  Power Line Frequency. Its simply the maximal amount of measurements my ultrasonic sensor HC-SR04 can take. @Wossname I can make it more than one edge for synchronization. The main part is that the Raspberry and the device have to be separated after a an amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

" the Raspberry and the device have to be separated after a an amount of time.  Separated for how long?

"as accurately as possible" can cost dollars, or thousands of dollars.  Please be more precise about this.  In terms of one oscillator period (20 ms), What is the timing difference you can tolerate?

+/-1 microsecond is only 20,000:1, very easy to meet with one CMOS counter.  Going farther, consider this.  An 819.2 kHz oscillator costs $6 at Digi-Key.  That, driving a CD4060 gives you a perfectly symmetrical 50 Hz square wave signal.  Build two of those.  When you tap the Reset inputs, that synchronizes two circuits to within 1.2 microseconds.

Two circuits, $14.  Good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Any oscillator needs a few swings until it is stable. So your idea isn't directly implementable. What you **can** do, however, is to synthesize the waveform you need.

Use one of the PWM outputs each Raspi has to generate a high-frequency rectangle wave with variable pulse width and feed that through a low-pass to get the desired waveform as a result. You only need a resistor and a capacitor for that, all else is software.

Comment: The question is poorly stated, but this is only likely to solve a small part of the problem.  The real issue is that the transmitter and receiver need to stay synchronized, without connection.

Answer (score 0):

You mention 50Hz frequency.  Does that mean that you are using Power Line Frequency?  If so, can you use that for synchronisation?

The RPi can be powered from a line-powered supply.  You can build a fairly simple opto-isolated zero-cross detector that can then feed the RPi.

Same with the transmitting device.  If it can be powered from the AC line and get a zero-cross sample, things will be easier.

Do note that there can be a couple of "Gotchas" with this approach.

1) If this is a Residential power system with only a single phase power source, things are easy.  Just detect both Zero-Cross points and transmit on both.  The RPi needs to detect only one of those transmissions.

2) If this is from a 3-phase power system, you have to do some math on the RPi.  The transmitting device will still transmit at every Zero-Cross point on the AC power signal.  But the RPi has to be able to detect the signal at any of 3 points on the 50 Hz AC waveform: 0, 120, 240 degrees.  You don't need the other logical points (180 degrees, etc) if the transmitting device sends data at each Zero-Cross point.

On the other hand - I could be completely out to lunch here.  That is - I might be trying to solve a different problem than what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Rpi's run anywhere from 250M to 1G (Rpi zero)but excluded a Time of Day (ToD) clock for cost reduction.

You would need to sync both units every hour or day to depending on ppm error if master clock, assuming it is constant... Syncing that to 50Hz pulses is possible but not just one as some countries shift f to balance loads whereas in other parts of the world , master grid suppliers were once GLobal click synchronized to 0.001 ppm or better.

You need to explore Adafruit addons and consider that multiplying or dividing 50 Hz to any other frequency still has the same ppm error of receiver after initial sync and must be corrected frequently to stay in sync. With the right counters and 1ppm GPS clock, some XTals can be tuned and you can buy 2ppm click chips cheap now in SMD in almost any freq. Some can be tuned to <1ppm with a mini oven and the right VCXO or VCTCXO, but XO's or Crystal Oscillators are 10k x better than a 555 in terms of parts per million (ppm) frequency error.

Answer (score -1):

The expensive, but highly accurate way to do this is to get 2 GPS disciplined oscillators, many of which have a 1 pulse per second output that is synchronized to GPS time (unless you plan to operate somewhere, such as underground, where sat signals can’t be acquired).

Then you can add uS calibrated digital delays for smaller time increments than 1 second.